# increase the stored procedure perfomance

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-express

Hi
I have the database with huge data. there are several master-detail relationships within it. so i just wanted to build the Views / stored procedure so that data fetching get much faster. I know I can use Index. but i saw it is a limitation in sql server express version. where as i am using express version. so how to perform this in express version. please guide me .

Comment: Views simply provide a convenient way to access data in a particular way. To a first approximation, they don't speed anything up. Are you perhaps referring to indexed views?

Comment: As i read that, Sql server express does not support Indexing. this is i think limitation

Comment: this statement is **plain wrong** - SQL Server Express **DOES** support indexing! You can create clustered and non-clustered, unique and other indices - not a problem at all ....

Comment: Also: which **version** of SQL Server Express?? Can you tell us a bit about your table structures? How much data is in those tables?? How do your stored procedures query that data?? What kind of indices do you already have in place ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a stored procedure won't speed up query execution.

Making sure that your foreign keys are indexed is the first step.
The definite answer to the question of query performance will give you a look at query execution plan. Make sure you don't have any Table Scans / Table Seeks.